# MySQL CSV import to include \\ string values inside?

Tags: mysql, csv, import, escaping

How to import a CSV containing a column with the strings like:

```
\\abc
```

The original value is escaped (changed) into MySQL as:

```
\abc
```

I don't want it to be changed. How can i stop it not to change the values?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you load your data with [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html), you should specify `FIELDS ESCAPED BY ''` in order to avoid treating a single `\` as an escape string.

If you are not using `LOAD DATA INFILE`, then the application you use to load the data is responsible for any unescaping that occurs, so you should provide details on that.